# How to save Canvas drawing to Firebase using Angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm building an angular app with Canvas drawing pad.
I used Angular SingnaturePad2 to get this working. 
https://github.com/lathonez/angular2-signaturepad-demo

How can I save canvas drawing to firebase realtime database or firebase storage? 
Which would be the best practice?

I just want users to log in and draw something and then save so they can see what they drew when log back in. 
However all drawings should be private. Users shouldn't be allowed to see each other's drawing.

When I click on submit, I get this kind of image string in console:

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

and I'm trying to save & retrieve this state using firebase.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload to Firebase Storage from a Data URL just use `putString` with the option `DATA_URL` [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage#.StringFormat).

Ex.

```
// `location` is the Firebase Storage reference;
// `type` is the image type (in your case 'image/png')
function uploadToStorage (location, canvas, type) {
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(type);

  return location.putString(dataURL, 'data_url')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting image string as you mentioned above just split image/png;base64 part from the string

```
       const file = fileData.split(',')[1];
        const metadata = {
            contentType: 'image/png',
        };
        const n = Date.now();

        // const userProfileRef = this.storage.ref(`gs://dentistry-project-dev.appspot.com/signature/${n}.png`);

    const userProfileRef = this.storage.ref(`/signature/${n}.png`);
        userProfileRef.putString(file, 'base64', metadata).then(snapshot => {
            console.log('snapShot',snapshot);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```